# understanding the purpose of using "new int[]"

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

//Search program
 void read_data(int* , int); //array address, size
int seq_search(int , int* , int);//key,array address,size
int binary_search(int , int* , int);

void main(void)
{
int  *arr , size , ans , key ;
cout << "Please enter the size: ";
cin >> size ;
arr = new int[size] ;
read_data(arr , size);
cout << "Enter the number to search for: ";
cin >> key ;
ans = binary_search(key, arr , size);
if(ans == -1)   
    cout << "The number " << key << " does not exist \n";
else    
    cout << "The number " << key << " exists at location " << ans << endl;
getch();
}

void read_data(int *pt , int ss)
{
cout << "Please enter " << ss << " numbers: \n";
for(int k = 0 ; k < ss ; k++)
{
    cout << "Enter the " << k + 1 << " number: " ;
    cin >> pt[k] ;
}
}

int seq_search(int num , int a[] , int s)
{
for(int k = 0 ; k < s ; k++)
    if(num == a[k])     { return k ; }
return -1 ;
}

int binary_search(int num , int a[] , int s)
{
int first , last , mid ;
first = 0 ;     last = s -1 ;
while(first <= last)
{
    mid = (first + last) / 2 ;
    if(num == a[mid])               return mid ;
    else if(num > a[mid])       first = mid + 1 ;
    else                                    
last   = mid - 1 ;
}
return -1;
}
```

From what I understood (I'm  a real beginner) is for example *P = a; points to address if integer a, and p = %a; is the reference or the real address of a.

I understood that we use this new int in order to use the array everywhere in the program as it is destroyed when main is finished, but why didn't I declare it outside of main too to be used everywhere?

Comment: This code is extremely hard to read... please look into proper indenting and code formatting!

Comment: If you are in an IDE, there should be a formatter.  But you should know the general structure for a language.

Answer (score 1):

> I understood that we use this new int in order to use the array everywhere in the program as it is destroyed when main is finished, but why didn't I declare it outside of main too to be used everywhere?

Whoever told you such a thing hates you with all his/her heart. Trust me.

You generally don't want to use `new` for nothing. The `new` operator dynamically allocates memory which **as a last resort** will be destroyed when the `main` exists (the programs end), even though I'm not sure this is actually guaranteed. But dynamically allocated memory that is not `delete`d will cause *memory leak*, which can be pretty dangerous in a program.

Most of the time there are better way to handle dynamically allocated resources and arrays of dynamic size (in this case [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)).

Just read a [good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn what `new` and `delete` actually means, and why you should avoid them.

Comment: My professor mentioned nothing on memory management which is most of what I find out when I read books c++ he justified it by saying we need to do so because the compiler can't compile a matrix without knowing how many address its going to take and because it will be destroyed out of main and it was left ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

To declare it outside main you would have to know the size of the array at compile time